# How to configure highlight panel for person account

Tags: lightning, person-accounts, highlights-panel

Our company is using Person Account to serve direct customers. I am trying to customize the Highlights Panel, however no luck in finding where I should go.

I tried to edit the compact layout in both Account and Contact objects but nor worked.

Answer (score 1):

Person Accounts have their separate page layouts. You will need to configure the Highlights Panel on the page layout specific to Person Accounts. To do so, follow the below steps (applicable for Lightning Experience).

- In Setup, go to Object Manager
- In Object Manager, search for Person Accounts in Quick Find
- Once you are in Person Account object, configure the Page Layout as required

Comment: Great and thanks! It works!

Comment: @Wesley glad that it helped. As you are new here, you should also familiarize yourself on some of the topics on SFSE. If your question gets answered and if it works, take a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)